# Decoding .wasm WebAssembly files

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Is there a way to decode .wasm WebAssembly files and either understand it or convert it to javascript?

for example I have [this script](https://static.florr.io/001cde8a187f58365176e79e85c00a079eaa9456/client.wasm) and I would like to know how to decode it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode a .wasm code? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418556/how-to-decode-a-wasm-code-is-it-possible)

Comment: @ZacharyHaber not as much as i would like

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways to decode a wasm file. The first, and simplest, is wasm2wat from the [WebAssembly Binary Toolkit](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt). This simply takes a binary wasm file and converts it into a human-readable text form ([WAT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format)). However, wasm is a compact and relatively low level binary format, and as a result, much of the information in the original code is lost. As a result, decompiled WAT files may not be that easy to read.

More recently, the Chrome team launched [wasm-decompile](https://v8.dev/blog/wasm-decompile), a tool that attempts to create a more readable decompiled output using a pseudo language that is quite readable (for JavaScript developers).